Bridgman on Eddington on relativistic energy tensor
Bridgman in his "The Nature of Thermodynamics" writes on  page 47, see here:

It is possible to restore verbal consistency to the general situation with regard to energy flow in stressed bodies... if we are willing to pay the price. A consistent verbalization is achieved by relativity theory; in fact one way of looking at relativity theory is that it is a method of achieving consistent verbalization subject to a few simple underlying physical postulates. The price that relativity theory demands that we pay for a consistent verbalization is that we give up thinking of energy as a thing with the simple properties of things and treat it instead as part of a higher complex, to the other members of which it is indissolubly tied. Consistency is achieved only by introducing the complete energy tensor of sixteen components, which are related not only to what we have been calling the energy, but also to the nine components of elastic stress, the three components of momentum, and the three components of the Poynting vector.   [...] The magnitude of the intellectual feat of getting formal consistency into this complicated situation has justly aroused universal admiration. But without minimizing the intellectual accomplishment, it is not unfair to point out that no new physics can be created by an essentially verbal procedure, Eddington to the contrary notwithstanding.

Can somebody explain to me what an essentially verbal procedure my have to do with Eddington; what is Bridgman talking about here?

It would be beneficial if you provide more passages and context.

@mauricio maybe you can help me to reformulate the question better but the archive.org link to the quote and with it to the whole book is on the 1st line. In the book the quote is preceded by a fascinating and truly Bridgmanian analysis of what a mechanical energy flux might mean. I am just curious what this cut to Eddington is referring to; Bridgman is usually very careful with his words.

You can edit your question to say what kind of energy concept is Bridgman describing and add more preceding passages where he uses the adjective "verbal"

In 1918 Eddington published Report on the Relativity Theory of Gravitation, which was the first introduction into Einstein's theory for the English speaking world. There he defined the energy tensor (p. 63) by what Bridgman calls "essentially verbal procedure" of folding energy, elastic stress, momentum and the Poynting vector into a single "higher complex". Apparently, Bridgman takes Eddington to present this as "creating new physics" and disagrees with him. He characterizes it as only "restoring verbal consistency".

@Conifold Oh, the history of it all, very interesting! Looking back 100 years later, do you agree with Bridgman? Anyhow, please, write this in an "answer", thank you.

@Conifold how Bridgman, the Grand Master of all Master Plumbers, must have disliked this sentence in Eddington: "The writer holds the view that the fundamental equations of gravitation (35.8), which on this theory are the sole basis of mechanics, should be regarded as a definition of matter rather than as a law of nature.... Matter does not cause the curvature (G) of spacetime; it is the curvature." (35.8 is $-8\pi T_{\sigma \tau}=G_{\sigma \tau}-\tfrac{1}{2}g_{\sigma \tau}G$)
